# Extract connection string from an Entity Connection String

Tags: .net, ado.net, web-config

When creating and ADO.NET Entity Connection String you get something like

```
<add name="MREntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.MembershipAndRoll.MembershipAndRollEntities.csdl|res://*/App_Code.MembershipAndRoll.MembershipAndRollEntities.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.MembershipAndRoll.MembershipAndRollEntities.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=192.168.0.26;User Id=digitaliv;password=*******;Persist Security Info=True;database=digitaliv&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My question is how do you grab the true inner connection string from that to call make a manual sql connection to call stored procedures, custom sql statements etc.? Specifically I need this part extracted from it

```
server=192.168.0.26;User Id=digitaliv;password=*******;Persist Security Info=True;database=digitaliv
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance of the `ObjectContext` (if you are using the built-in designer, your context derives from the EF `ObjectContext` class). You can cast the value of the `ObjectContext.Connection` property (which is a DbConnection) to an `EntityConnection`.

The `EntityConnection` class has a property `StoreConnection` which is the actual `DbConnection` used to connect to the database. This one actually has the `ConnectionString` property set to the one you are looking for.

Edit: Some sample code (Assign context to your ObjectContext):

```
ObjectContext context = entities;
EntityConnection entityConnection = context.Connection as EntityConnection;
if (null != entityConnection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entityConnection.StoreConnection.ConnectionString);
}
```

Comment: @dko There might be situations in which the ObjectContext.Connection property isn't an EntityConnection (although I couldn't enforce this behavior in my tests). Use the debugger to inspect the ObjectContext if this is the case for you.

Comment: I was just doing that as your wrote it. It works btw. Thank you

Comment: To do it in one line: ((System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString

Comment: If your the password in the connection string doesn't get carried over, be sure to set the "Persist Security Info" value to true.  Something I stumbled with when using the StoredConnectionString.

Answer (score 26):

While Jan Remunda rightly points out that you don't need to create a context, and while his solution is useful if you want to create a connection explicitly right after reading the `EntityClient` connection string, it's still a little convoluted if all you want is to retrieve the inner-provider connection string (which is what OP asks).

It's true that you don't have to open the connection, you can just retrieve the `ConnectionString` of the inner `StoreConnection` then discard it right after, but why?

Use the appropriate connection string builder instead:

```
new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(outerConnectionString).ProviderConnectionString
```

See [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder).

Comment: That's exactly what the OP was asking for and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. If someone needs getting connection string from web.config here is the example: EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbContextConnectionName"].ConnectionString).ProviderConnectionString

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to create instance of ObjectContext. Because in that case you must reference assemblies where metadata are stored and for performance is not also very good.

There is simpler way to get provider connection string in StoreConnection property.

```
 using (var ec = new EntityConnection(connstr.ConnectionString))
 {
   var sqlConn = ec.StoreConnection as SqlConnection;
   sqlConn.Open();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following code to extract connection string only from entity framework connection string without metadata information.

```
string connectionString = new MREntities().Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

Answer (score -5):

try this :

```
conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MREntities"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Yes that gives the whole etadata=res://*/App_Code.MembershipAndRoll.MembershipAndRollEntities.csdl|res://*/App_Code.MembershipAndRoll.MembershipAndRollEntities.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.MembershipAndRoll.MembershipAndRollEntities.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=192.168.0.26;User Id=digitaliv;password=*******;Persist Security Info=True;database=digitaliv&quot; part i just need the server=192.168.0.26;User Id=digitaliv;password=*******;Persist Security Info=True;database=digitaliv part