# Entity Framework getting an sql connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the light of [Closing connections explicitly in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285877/closing-connections-explicitly-in-entity-framework) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738582%28v=vs.90%29.aspx it seems that I should be using the context to create connections rather than doing the following

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=(local)"))
{
    ...
}
```

My understanding is that I'll

- Get rid of the connection string
- Utilize connection pooling built into EF

But how do I acquire an SQL connection through the context?

Comment: What do you want the SQL Connection for? There's probably a way to do what you want directly in EF without the need for the actual `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract connection string from an Entity Connection String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136919/extract-connection-string-from-an-entity-connection-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out that the magic lies in **ExecuteStoreCommand()**

```
  new AdventureEntities().ExecuteStoreCommand(
        @"    UPDATE Users
              SET lname = @lname 
              WHERE Id = @id",
        new SqlParameter("lname", lname), new SqlParameter("id", id));
```

Then there is no need for an explicit Connection, it actually made the code a lot cleaner. The one-liner above replaced all of the following code

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=(local)"))
  {
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
      cmd.CommandText = @"
          UPDATE Users
          SET lname = @lname 
          WHERE Id = @id";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", lname);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes that was one solution I described in question you deleted. But there is even one better without calling SQL manually. Check ObjectStateManager, GetObjectStateEntry, ObjectStateEntry and SetModifiedProperty.

Comment: It was deleted as the problem got messed up in the question. Can you repose the answer here and I'll accept it

Comment: I already voted there for reopen so I will wait if other users with high rep. will vote as well before making duplicit answer.

Answer (score 20):

In EF5 (changed for EF6) the following would return the connection:

```
var connection = ((EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection;
```

<strike>If you are using EF in a right way you will probably never need to get inner db connection.</strike>

Comment: context.Connection was removed since EF6

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij in EF6 you can use `context.Database.Connection`

Answer (score 11):

I used next code to getting connection (Entity Framework 5.0):

```
var connection = Context.Database.Connection;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var efConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(efConnectionString);
string sqlConnectionString = efConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 5):

If the EF connection string is stored in your web config file, you can assign it to a SQL Data Source with this code:

```
            var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataEntities"].ConnectionString;
            EntityConnection ec = new EntityConnection(connString);
            var storeConnect = ec.StoreConnection;

            SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = storeConnect.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the easiest way to create a SqlConnection in EF6 is to do the following:

```
DBContext context = new DBContext();
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following as well. I wanted to inject some Dapper.NET into a existing project that already had Entity framework entity context so I created the following:

```
public class EFConnectionAccessor : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlConnection sqlConnection;
    private readonly MyEntities entities;

    public EFConnectionAccessor()
    {
        entities = new MyEntities();

        var entityConnection = entities.Connection as EntityConnection;

        if (entityConnection != null)
        {
            sqlConnection = entityConnection.StoreConnection as SqlConnection;
        }
    }

    public SqlConnection connection
    {
        get
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            return sqlConnection;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
        sqlConnection.Dispose();
        entities.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Called using

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new EFConnectionAccessor().connection)
{
 // ADO.NET CODE HERE - Or in my case dapper.net
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the DataContext will allow you to call your Entity Objects right off of your DataContext reference, abstracting away all of the details of the underlying connection logistics.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to fire an UPDATE statement without first reading in the entity - hence I need an SQLConnection

Comment: it connects automaticly so to speak , you can fire the update and its then when EF connects.(unless you do other stuff before that )