# Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.? with Sql Connection in Entityt Framework with MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I  am  using  Entity Framework 4 with my Asp.Net MVC3  application. My  problem  is  that  I  am  using  Entity Framework  to  perform  action  with  my  database ,  That  is  working  fine.  For  some  other  purpose I am  also  using  Sql Connection  to  Store  and  Retrieve  my  data  from database. I  am  getting

```
[Keyword not supported: 'metadata']
```

error   while  connecting  with  my  database.

This  is  my  web  config

```
  <add name="VibrantEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Vibrant.csdl|res://*/Vibrant.ssdl|res://*/Vibrant.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KAPS-PC\KAPSSERVER;initial catalog=vibrant;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I  am  using  class  Library,  So  this  is  my   App Config.

```
   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

   <add name="VibrantEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Vibrant.csdl|res://*/Vibrant.ssdl|res://*/Vibrant.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KAPS-PC\KAPSSERVER;initial catalog=vibrant;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The connection string for ADO.NET (in this case `SqlConnection`) doesn't take that format. You're using the one specific for Entity Framework. The ADO.NET one should be something like:

```
"data source=KAPS-PC\KAPSSERVER;initial catalog=vibrant;integrated security=True"
```

So, to sum it up, you need two separate connection strings, one for EF and one for ADO.NET

Answer (score 19):

You connection string is specific to Entity Framework and contains metadata. You need to get your provider connection string from it. You can do it using [`EntityConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.providerconnectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var efConnectionString = "Your Entity Framework connection string";
var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(efConnectionString);
var regularConnectionString = builder.ProviderConnectionString;
```

Comment: Short, precise and easy to follow! Thanks

Comment: Hi, where should I write this code ? is it in the web.config ?

Comment: @kurniawan26 you can't write C# code in your `web.config`. You will need to use it wherever you connect to the database. Your connection string should live in `web.config` though. You can post your code in a separate question and I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 6):

Another option (other than 2 separate connection strings for the same thing) is to build a method that returns an ADO.NET connection string from your Entity Framework object:

```
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
...
private string GetADOConnectionString()
{
    SalesSyncEntities ctx = new SalesSyncEntities(); //create your entity object here
    EntityConnection ec = (EntityConnection)ctx.Connection;
    SqlConnection sc = (SqlConnection)ec.StoreConnection; //get the SQLConnection that your entity object would use
    string adoConnStr = sc.ConnectionString;
    return adoConnStr;
}
```

(I place this somewhere in my Class Library where my edmx files are)

(I got this from http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2009/11/getting-sqlconnection-from.html)

Or even better... if your SQLConnection stuff are manual SQL queries, skip the SQLConnection entirely via the ExecuteStoredCommand:

```
new AdventureEntities().ExecuteStoreCommand(
        @"    UPDATE Users
              SET lname = @lname 
              WHERE Id = @id",
        new SqlParameter("lname", lname), new SqlParameter("id", id));
```

(I got this from [Entity Framework getting an sql connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286071/entity-framework-getting-an-sql-connection))

Answer (score -1):

Theres a better solution here, use the Entity Framework Power tools, reverse engineer your database into your project, then you can use a single EF connection string (which is a normal connection string) for both scenarios.

Comment: i  didn't   get   you  , can  you  explain   more