# ASP.NET manage site settings globally using database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working on a project where I need to store settings for various areas in the application. These settings aren't stored in the app.config because there is an admin page where the admin can change the settings (client does not want these settings in the app.config)

I tried to implement a static class to access the settings globally but my concern is using the dbcontext in a static class as I don't think it's the best choice as well i'd like the settings to be strongly-typed and right now everything is a string.

I am not sure how else I can access my appsettings table in the database and still make it easy to call throughout the application, like ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["settingName"];

```
public static class AppManager
{
    private static readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new DatabaseContext());

    public static IEnumerable<AppSetting> GetAll()
    {
        return UnitOfWork.AppSettings.GetAll();
    }

    public static AppSetting Get(Guid id)
    {
        return UnitOfWork.AppSettings.Get(id);
    }

    public static string GetValue(string name)
    {
        return UnitOfWork.AppSettings.GetValue(name);
    }

    public static void Update(string name, string value)
    {
        var setting = UnitOfWork.AppSettings.Get(name);
        if(setting == null) return;

        setting.Value = value;

        UnitOfWork.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am not sure how else I can access my appsettings table in the database and still make it easy to call throughout the application, like ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["settingName"];` what do you mean by this statement .. you can  still use the `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["DbConn"];` setup a value in the config to for the connection string.. and if you're using EntityFramework then checkout this link for connection strings [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: I have a table in my database where I store the app settings. I am having issues accessing my database context statically. My understanding is using the dbcontext statically isn't a good idea so I am trying to figure out the easiest way to get values from this table globally.

Comment: Checkout this as well as do a google search on DBContext connection strings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003797/get-the-entity-framework-connection-string

Comment: @MethodMan You appear to have misunderstood the question. He appears to know how to store settings in the app.config, but he doesn't know how to properly design his application in order to make database access as easy as pulling settings from the config file.

Comment: @mason I think that he needs to edit the question then..I totally understand that he wants to pull the setting from a database. vs storing them in the .Config file..

Comment: My question is simply, how do I access my database context to retrieve the data in a globally accessible way. My thoughts are to use a static but I don't know how to use my dbcontext in a static class and I am not sure if that's the best thing to be doing.

Comment: A static class will work fine. If you really want a better architecture, you can look up the service or repository patterns. Then you'd have a non-static class and you would use Dependency Injection to inject the class into your controllers or forms where you need it. But that's too big a topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: How/What does a static implementation look like? Do you use a Using statement? or something else?